# Geometry suddenly got merged together like Union effect in my Object

Tags: geometry

Please help i don't know what i did. why all of my geometric shapes got unioned together at some point in time. I used to be able to select each shape (cube, sphere, cylinder, etc) with "L" in the whole object in Edit mode. I only remember doing "Cleanup -> Merge Vertices 0.0001m" but never did i intend to do anything to merge (union) everything together into one interconnected geometry. What could i have possibly done?

Comment: Well, if the geometries were very close together and you merged them using the Cleanup > Merge by Distance tool, they're gonna... merge. You can only undo, or manually select and separate them. Are you saying they got merged even though they were *not* close together? Please be more specific, with screenshots or files, if possible.

Comment: oh yeah you are right... oh noooo. so i guess i cant do a cleanup and still keep objects separate damn. oh.. well i can still do the 0.0001m merge but i need to be careful next time. thanks for pointing that out

Comment: You can select all and press P > By loose parts to separate your mesh islands into individual objects first, if that's what you want.

Comment: yeah i already tried but they are already merged coz i did merge with a slightly higher value than 0.0001m

Comment: Yeah, you have to do it before merging :)

Comment: but im glad i know now the cause. not a mystery anymore  thanks man. can u put that as answer and i will check it. so we can close this thread :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the geometries are very close together and you merge them using the *Cleanup > Merge > by Distance* tool, they're gonna... merge. You can only undo, or manually select and separate them afterwards. If you're unsure about a cleanup operation and would like to keep mesh island intact, you might wanna first separate them into individual objects with <kbd>P</kbd> *> By loose parts*. Now with multiple individual objects selected, you can <kbd>Tab</kbd> back into *Edit Mode* and do a cleanup of all of them at once without having them joined together.

Comment: perfect! love this answer! thanks mate!